# Unit test for useReducer hook with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a code like below:

```
export default function func() {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(
   (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}),
   {loading: false, name: ""}
  );

  if(state.loading) {
    return <Loader />
  }
  return (
    <div>{state.name}</div>  
  );
}
```

I have been searching for this in google but did not find the expected result.
so What is the best way to write unit test for this component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This code just initializes the state using the default value, there is no action to change this state, only to test the initialized state of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to extract your reducer into a separate testable function, like so:

```
export default function func() {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    name: ""
  });

  if (state.loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  return (
    <div>{ state.name }</div>
  );
}

export const reducer = (state, newState) => ({
  ...state,
  ...newState,
})
```

Additionally, when using the reducer pattern your second parameter is typically an "action" that describes a certain operation. [Here's an article describing this pattern in depth](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/the-state-reducer-pattern-with-react-hooks).